# How to rewrite to subdomain using nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

i want to join two seperate servers by url rewrite.

When mysite.com/blog/blog-title -> wp.mysite.com/blog-title

Two servers are in aws too. There is a front cloudflare dns setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try out below code, try to put 'if' block at the start,

```
server {
   ...
   if ($request_uri ~* "/blog/(.*)" ) {
      return 301 http://wp.mysite.com/$1;
   }
   ...
}
```

Edited w.r.t. comment below,

```
server {
   ...
   location /blog {
      rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://wp.mysite.com;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Return statement probably redirects page. i want to serve site in /blog/ slug.

Comment: do you want to keep the url as <mysite.com/blog/blog-title> and bring data from <wp.mysite.com/blog-title>? then i'll edit answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly <mysite.com/blog/blog-title>

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check that out, and accept it if that works :)

Comment: I'd already figured out proxy_pass. That's working. Thank you